# beginner tutorial catkin_make error directory not found

Tags: ros, c++, catkin-make, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to catkin_make packages but it fais:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:64 (message) : add_message_files() directory not found: /home/user/catkin_ws/src/msg
```

I can't understand why it tries to find msg files in src/msg.

catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED PACKAGES roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)

add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
DEPENDS system_lib)
    
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_message_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_message_cpp)
```

catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(beginner_tutorials)
    
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED PACKAGES roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)
    
    add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
    add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
    
    generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
    
    catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
    DEPENDS system_lib)
            
    include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
    add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_message_cpp)

    add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
    add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_message_cpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67415/beginner-tutorial-catkin_make-error-directory-not-found/) by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-15**:
Can you please be more clear and explain more about what you are doing. Can you tell me if you sourced the file and can you output you ROS path.

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2013-07-15**:
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros, I'm studying tutorial "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)" and try to make packages. Previously I created msg and srv files in corresponding paths in beginner_tutorial.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-16**:
Could you show your CMake file ?

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2013-07-16**:
Done, Lucile

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-16**:
Did you generate your catkin workspace with catkin_init_workspace ? If so, your catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt should be totally different. Anyway, you ask for Num.msg and AddTwoInts.srv in src folder and I think that's why cmake looks for them in src/msg folder.

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2013-07-16**:
Yes, but I accidentally delete CMakeLists.txt in catkin_ws/src and tried to generate it using catkin_init_workspace once again, and it created that file. I can't find an example of necessary file to copy in catkin_ws/src.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-16**:
just do another catkin_workspace then to run the publisher example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure which tutorial you were referring to, but assuming it was one of [basic tutorials listed here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials):

```
directory not found: /home/user/catkin_ws/src/msg
```

No tutorial instructs you to create a `msg` directory under `src` directory. Instead, [like this section](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg), you're supposed to create INSIDE of a `beginner_tutorials` package.

```
catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeList.txt
```

So yes, `CMakeLists.txt` you were editing is for `beginner_tutorials` package, and because the `add_message_files` macro is in there, it should make sense to you to have `msg` in the package too.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0